# How to plot $f(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4+1}$ in MATLAB?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do I plot or how does the following function look?

$$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4+1}$$

I could rewrite this $$\frac{1}{r^4+1}.$$

Comment: Take a look at [2-D and 3-D Plots](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/plots.html).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using mesh/meshgrid functions? In your case it should look like this

```
[x y]=meshgrid(from:step:to);
z=1./(x.^4+2x.^2y.^2+y.^4+1);
mesh(x,y,z);
```

Answer (score -1):

There is the function called `fsurf()` to plot the surface. The usage is:

```
f1 = @(x,y) 1/(x^4+2*x^2*y^2+y^4+1);
fsurf(f1,[-5 5 -5 5])
```

It generates the graph show here -- [Output of fsurf()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cW6ks.png). The same can also be done using `mesh()` as mentioned by @polko14.

```
[x, y]=meshgrid(-5:0.1:5);
z=1./(x.^4+2*x.^2.*y.^2+y.^4+1);
mesh(x,y,z);
```

which generates the same plot -- [Output of mesh()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FCkJ.png).